# Mark a location on map for windows app

Tags: html, windows-10, oracle-maf

I am trying to mark a location on map using a link in Windows 10 app.

Tried using urlscheme `maps:q=<location>` and `geo:0,0?q=<location>` for anchor tag `<a></a>`.

Both of the URL scheme launches the Map app installed in device, but the location is not getting marked on the map.

I tried `geo:0,0?q=<location>` for Android and `maps:q=<location>`for iOS which is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

For windows we can use the Bing map app
URL Scheme for searching and marking a location on map in Windows is `'bingmaps:?where='<location>`

More details are available at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-maps-app